# Twig template variable of variable

Tags: symfony, twig

I have double for inside a twig template:

```
<table>
   {% for user in users %}
      <tr>
         {% for field in fields %}
            <td>{{ user.{{field}}  }}</td>
         {% endfor %}   
      </tr>
   {% endfor %} 
</table>
```

this can be done? what would be the correct syntax for **{{ user.{{field}}  }}**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute function does this, it can be used to access a "dynamic" attribute of a variable:

```
<table>
   {% for user in users %}
      <tr>
         {% for field in fields %}
            <td>{{ attribute(user,field) }}</td>
         {% endfor %}   
      </tr>
   {% endfor %} 
</table>
```

So the correct syntax is **{{ attribute(user,field) }}**, read the documentation [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the user has one-to-many relationship with field (i.e. one user can have multiple fields), and it's defined as such in ORM mapping and in the entities (i.e. the `User` entity has a `getFields()` method, which returns a collection of `Field` entities), then you can do this:

```
<table>
   {% for user in users %}
      <tr>
         {% for field in user.fields %}
            <td>{{ field }}</td>
         {% endfor %}   
      </tr>
   {% endfor %} 
</table>
```

But if that's not the case, then it might help to describe a little bit more about what kind of relationship a User has with its fields.